# Pressing Alt+= in Word 2010 does not activate the math typesetting tool

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I read about the math typesetting tool of Word 2007, which should work in Word 2010 as well. I tried many times to activate that tool in my Word 2010, but the keystrokes combinations associated with it (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>) does not work.

Any idea why?

Comment: If you hover over the Equation button under the Insert tab, do you see the tooltip with the keyboard shortcut listed? http://i.imgur.com/0BGCLIA.png

Comment: I failed to reproduce this. Alt+= works perfectly well for me. I tried Word 2007, 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

How to assign a shortcut to "Insert New Equation":

- Click "File" menu, "Word Options".
- Click "Customize Ribbon".
- Next to "Keyboard shortcuts", click "Customize..."
- Under Categories, select "All Commands".
- Under Commands, select "EquationToggle".
- Select "Press new shortcut key", and press both "Alt" and "=".
- Click "Assign".

You can see if a shortcut is already assigned after selecting "EquationToggle".

Usually you can insert an equation from "Insert" menu, "Equation" on the right, "Insert New Equation" at the bottom.